# Proving `forall x xs ys, subseq (x :: xs) ys -> subseq xs ys` in Coq

Tags: coq, proof, theorem-proving

I have the following definition

```
Inductive subseq : list nat -> list nat -> Prop :=
| empty_subseq : subseq [] []
| add_right : forall y xs ys, subseq xs ys -> subseq xs (y::ys)
| add_both : forall x y xs ys, subseq xs ys -> subseq (x::xs) (y::ys)
.
```

Using this, I wish to prove the following lemma

```
Lemma del_l_preserves_subseq : forall x xs ys, subseq (x :: xs) ys -> subseq xs ys.
```

So, I tried looking at the proof of `subseq (x :: xs) ys` by doing `destruct H`.

```
Proof.
  intros. induction H.
```

```
3 subgoals (ID 209)

  x : nat
  xs : list nat
  ============================
  subseq xs [ ]

subgoal 2 (ID 216) is:
 subseq xs (y :: ys)
subgoal 3 (ID 222) is:
 subseq xs (y :: ys)
```

Why does the first subgoal ask me to prove `subseq xs []`? Shouldn't the `destruct` tactic know that the proof cannot be of the form `empty_subseq` since the type contains `x :: xs` and not `[]`?

In general how do I prove the lemma that I am trying to prove?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Shouldn't the destruct tactic know that the proof cannot be of the form empty_subseq since the type contains x :: xs and not []?

In fact, `destruct` doesn't know that much. It just replaces `x :: xs` and `xs` with `[]` and `[]` in the `empty_subseq` case. In particular, this frequently leads to lost information in the context. Better alternatives:

- Use `inversion` instead of `destruct`.
- Use `remember` to ensure both type indices of `subseq` are variables before `destruct`. (`remember (x :: xs) as xxs in H.`) This more explicit goal management also works well with `induction`.

Answer (score 0):

Li-yao's answer was actually useful. This is a proof of the lemma.

```
Lemma del_l_preserves_subseq : forall x xs ys, subseq (x :: xs) ys -> subseq xs ys.
Proof.
  intros x xs ys.
  induction ys as [|y ys'].
  - intros. inversion H. (* Inversion will detect that no constructor matches the type of H *)
  - intros. inversion H. (* Inversion will automatically discharge the first case *)
    + (* When [subseq (x :: xs) ys'] holds *)
      apply IHys' in H2. now apply add_right.
    + (* When [subseq xs ys'] holds *)
      now apply add_right.
Qed
```